# Apache-beam Bigquery .fromQuery ClassCastException

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to execute a query against a `BigQuery` table, extract one column and populate to a file.
The code below throws an exception. I could be wrong but it seems the process is trying write temporary results to temp location as avro format, read the data from it and throws cast exception.

```
pipeLine.apply(
        BigQueryIO.read(
                (SchemaAndRecord elem) -> {
                  GenericRecord record = elem.getRecord();
                  return (String) record.get("column");
                })
                .fromQuery("SELECT column FROM `project.dataset.table`")
                .usingStandardSql()
                .withCoder(AvroCoder.of(String.class)))
        .apply(TextIO.write().to("gs://bucket/test/result/data")
                .withSuffix(TXT_EXT)
                .withCompression(Compression.GZIP));
```

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.avro.util.Utf8
>   cannot be cast to java.lang.String    at
>   xxxxx.xxx.xxx.sampling.dataflow.samplingextractor.service.BigQueryExportService.lambda$export$43268ee4$1(BigQueryExportService.java:137)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQuerySourceBase$1.apply(BigQuerySourceBase.java:242)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQuerySourceBase$1.apply(BigQuerySourceBase.java:235)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.io.AvroSource$AvroBlock.readNextRecord(AvroSource.java:597)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.io.BlockBasedSource$BlockBasedReader.readNextRecord(BlockBasedSource.java:209)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileBasedSource$FileBasedReader.advanceImpl(FileBasedSource.java:484)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileBasedSource$FileBasedReader.startImpl(FileBasedSource.java:479)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.io.OffsetBasedSource$OffsetBasedReader.start(OffsetBasedSource.java:249)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.WorkerCustomSources$BoundedReaderIterator.start(WorkerCustomSources.java:601)

Comment: Have you tested the @Haris Nadeem approach? It seems right

Comment: It doesn't work.  I tried it before posting this question.

Comment: Did you get the same error?

Comment: Yes.  it is throwing the same error.

Comment: Are you running it on DataFlow or DirectRunner?

Comment: I'mn running Dataflow

Comment: In the documentation (https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.2.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.TypedRead.html#withCoder-org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.Coder-)  its said:  "Sets a Coder for the result of the parse function. This may be required if a coder can not be inferred automatically."   Did you try removing this part of the code?

Answer (score 0):

I think it suggests you use `.withCoder(AvroCoder.of(org.apache.avro.util.Utf8.class)))` as String cannot be converted from Avro Utf8 class directly.

Comment: Can't put this together AvroCoder.of(org.apache.avro.util.Utf8.class))

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the [documentation here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/#reading-with-a-query-string), it seems you want to simply use the [StringUtf8Coder](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.1.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/coders/StringUtf8Coder.html) class.

```java
pipeLine.apply(
    BigQueryIO.read(
            (SchemaAndRecord elem) -> {
              GenericRecord record = elem.getRecord();
              return (String) record.get("column");
            })
            .fromQuery("SELECT column FROM `project.dataset.table`")
            .usingStandardSql()
            .withCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of()))
        .apply(TextIO.write().to("gs://bucket/test/result/data")
            .withSuffix(TXT_EXT)
            .withCompression(Compression.GZIP));
```

Comment: This approach seems to be right @Jay Yoo. Have you tested it?